# Instagram API: How to get pictures by tag name

Tags: javascript, api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to get recent pictures by tagname. In [API Doc](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/) I found that I need to send request to `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

I'm using JavaScript (node.js), **But this is not JavaScript specific question** ,so you can skip the code.

**Note:** access_token is valid, I checked.

here is my code:

```
 var tag = 'nexus5x';
 var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'+ tag +'?access_token=' + access_token;

 request({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET'
 }, function(error, response, body){
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(body);
    }
    console.log('done');
 });
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVo1V.png)

So it requires `max_tag_id` or `min_tag_id`. But i don't have max/min id as I'm requesting first time and pagination object is empty

Answer (score 1):

If you are in sandbox mode, you will only get maximum 20 pics in API response and there will be no pagination, also u will see only pics from your sandbox authorized users, more info on sandbox mode here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

`max_tag_id` and `min_tag_id` are not required for the first call, once your app is live, you will have pagination object and the `next_url` will have all the relevant `max_tag_id` in the url.